# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

pesquisei sobre e falaram que era porque o HTML tava sendo carregado antes do JS vice versa, a soluçao era mudar o lugar das chamadas dos scripts, colquei em tudo que é lugar e nada

```
<div id="content">
    <b id="bt_cad">cadastre se</b>
</div>

var content = document.getElementById('content');
bt_cad.click(function() {
    log.css("display", "none");
    cad.css("display", "block");

    var c_form_cad = document.createElement('form');
    c_form_cad.method="post";
    c_form_cad.id="form_cad";
    c_form_cad.autocomplete="off";

    // erro no appendChild
    document.getElementById(c_form_cad.id="form_cad").appendChild(content);

    console.log(content);
    console.log(c_form_cad);
});
```

Comment: É sempre bom referenciar um `id` usando, ou `document.getElementById` ou `document.querySelector`, em vez de fazer assim `bt_cad.click`. Ou seja, seria `document.getElementById("bt_cad").click` ou `document.querySelector("#bt_cad").click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando seu código o problema é que `c_form_cad` (form) foi criado mas não foi adicionado na pagina ainda então o `document.getElementById` vai retornar `null`.

Outro ponto é que neste caso o `c_form_cad` já é o elemento que você quer então não há necessidade de fazer um `document.getElementById`, basta usar o `c_form_cad`.

```
// document.getElementById(c_form_cad.id="form_cad").appendChild(content);
c_form_cad.appendChild(content);


// não esqueça de adicionar a pagina, algo parecido como o comando abaixo
document.body.appendChild( c_form_cad );
```

uma outra coisa dando uma segunda olhada pode ser que você esteja querendo fazer o contrario, ou seja, adicionar o `form` dentro da `div#content` se for esse o caso o codigo correto seria

```
content.appendChild( c_form_cad );
```

Comment: o man só mais uma coisa nessa linha `c_form_cad.id="form_cad"` atribuo o id, não tem como atribuir uma `class` tbm? tentei assim `c_form_cad.class="form_cad";`

Comment: tem sim usando `c_form_cad.className="form_cad";`